# Is "Foundation Blender Compositing" by Roger Wickes of any use?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have a copy of Foundation Blender Compositing by Roger Wickes. Soon after I bought it I realised it was outdated. What and how can I get any value from this book? Or should I shelve it in the archives?

Comment: Blender version pre 2.5

Comment: I think you're better off ditching it. Sorry.

Comment: Well, since the book has a good reputation, it seems, I guess the "compositing " concepts should be good, well explained and perhaps still valid. Of course current blender versions are too different than whatever version (guess 2.49) he used as reference in the book, but you could also learn the new tools, and experiment the concepts, maybe helping yourself running also a 2.49 blender copy (just download it from http://download.blender.org/release/) to be able to follow his steps on the book, when it's too different. I hope files saved in 2.49 could be loadable even from latest... perhaps.

Comment: Thank you @m.ardito, I didn't think of that!

Comment: Don't waste your time learning blender's old interface. Even though some core concepts are the same, the changes after 2.5 mean that you will have to re-learn the new interface anyway. Trying to follow any tutorial using an old blender is only going to give you headaches.

Comment: @cegaton Thank you for your opinion. But have you got an alternative book or know of any upgrade of Foundation Blender Compositing that has the detail of that book?